# Adding a Link/Template Column to a Custom Table Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table component built based off of this article: [Creating an Angular2 Datatable from Scratch](http://4dev.tech/2016/09/creating-an-angular2-datatable-from-scratch/).

I've been extending it so do different things that I need for my app (like sorting and paging), but one thing I can't figure out is how to provide some sort of "Template column" to allow for creation of things like edit/delete links.

I tried figuring out how to get `<ng-content>` to work in the `ColumnComponent` so that I could pass in a link/routerlink template that way, but I don't get how to do that with the way this table is built.

Here is a tripped-down version of my components:

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5iBUR11CR6B653HpgaMW?p=preview)

The (simplified) components as they stand now:

**datatable.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let column of columns">
              {{column.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let row of dataset; let i = index">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let column of columns">
              {{row[column.value]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**datatable.component.ts**

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable, Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ColumnComponent } from './column.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'datatable',
    templateUrl: 'src/datatable.component.html'
})
export class DatatableComponent {

    @Input() dataset;
    columns: ColumnComponent[] = [];
    addColumn(column) {
        this.columns.push(column);
    }
}
```

**column.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {DatatableComponent} from './datatable.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'column',
  template: ``,

})
export class ColumnComponent {
    @Input() value: string;
    @Input() header: string;

    constructor(public table: DatatableComponent) {
        table.addColumn(this);
    }
}
```

**Example Component Markup For Existing Components**

```
<datatable  [dataset]="photoData">
    <column [value]="'id'" [header]="'ID'"></column>
    <column [value]="'title'" [header]="'Title'"></column>
</datatable>
```

**Desired Markup Example**
Doesn't have to be exactly like this, but I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
<datatable  [dataset]="photoData">
    <column [value]="'id'" [header]="Edit">
         This is a custom edit link column:
         <a [routerLink]="['/edit/', id]">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>
         </a>
    </column>
    <column [value]="'id'" [header]="'ID'"></column>
    <column [value]="'title'" [header]="'Title'"></column>
</datatable>
```

Comment: I don't see where are you using ng-content in your plunker

Comment: I'm not, what I have there is a working example of what I have now, the problem is I don't know how to add the `ng-content` functionality and get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would leverage `ngTemplateOutlet` to achieve it.

Create references to possible templates for your

**column.component.ts**

```
@ContentChild('tableHeaderTemplate') headerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
@ContentChild('tableBodyTemplate') bodyTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

So we can now use custom template for header or body if we provided it

**datatable.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
           <ng-container *ngIf="!col.headerTemplate">{{col.header}}</ng-container> 
           <ng-template *ngIf="col.headerTemplate" [ngTemplateOutlet]="col.headerTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: { header: col.header } }"></ng-template>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let row of dataset; let i = index">
      <tr>
        <td  *ngFor="let col of columns">
          <ng-container *ngIf="!col.bodyTemplate">{{row[col.value]}}</ng-container> 
          <ng-template *ngIf="col.bodyTemplate" [ngTemplateOutlet]="col.bodyTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: { value: row[col.value] }, row: row }"></ng-template>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and finally table definition might look like:

```
<datatable  [dataset]="photoData">
    <column [value]="'id'" [header]="'ID'"></column>
    <column [value]="'title'" [header]="'Title'">
        <ng-template #tableHeaderTemplate let-column>
            <span style="color: red">{{ column.header }}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </column>
    <column [value]="'title'" [header]="'Actions'">
      <ng-template #tableBodyTemplate let-column let-row="row">
          <button (click)="remove(row.id)">Remove {{row.id}}</button>
      </ng-template>
    </column>
</datatable>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/CLkwkBqBpSc7hyPTHszA?p=preview)**

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting (got assigned to some other projects),and thank you, this works perfect!