# Angular ng-template, ngTemplateOutlet and ngTemplateOutletContext correct usage

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have been looking over the docs for a long time but havent been able to figure out what ng-template, ngTemplateOutlet and ngTemplateOutletContext can do to achieve the following scenario :

I have a grid component which fetches data from a service itself

```
`<my-grid [httpMethod]="'get'" [httpUrl]="'/data/gridservice'">
   <column [header]="'country'"></column>
   <column [header]="'capital'"></column>
</my-grid>`
```

and now i want to be able to customize the grid cell when the component is used wherein the user puts in the markup

```
`<my-grid [httpMethod]="'get'" [httpUrl]="'/data/gridservice'">
   <column [header]="'country'">
    <ng-template> 
      <img src="{{data.countryImg}}
      {{data.countryName}}
    </ng-template>
   </column>
   <column [header]="'capital'"></column>
</my-grid>`
```

How do i achieve this, also can this be achieved in recusrive components like angular tree?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586743/adding-a-link-template-column-to-a-custom-table-component/42588759#42588759

Comment: you might find [this article](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02) helpful, it explains in details what `ngTemplateOutlet` and `ngComponentOutlet` under the hood

Comment: Fully agree with @Maximus. It's great article. Each should read it

Comment: thankyou ..will refer and get back if i get more queries !