# Angular 5.0 Directive how to bind values in template while passed as attribute

Tags: angular

I am trying to create directive in my project which is in angular 5.0.
I am passing values from my component inside directive attribute and then inside directive I want to use *ngFor to display array of objects while doing so I am having issues. my component file

```
   <ng-template cpLoop #thing="items" [cpLoopOf]="coverages">
       {{ items.cpLoopOf}}
    <div *ngFor="let header of items.cpLoopOf">
      {{ header }}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

now inside my directive I am getting values through input

```
import { Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, Input, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ 
     selector: '[cpLoop]',
     inputs:['cpLoopOf'],
     exportAs: 'items'
})
export class CpLoopDecorator implements OnInit {
    @Input('cpLoopOf') cpLoopOf:any[];
    constructor( private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
                 private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { 

                    console.log(this.cpLoopOf);
                 }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.cpLoopOf);
      }
}
```

Now here when I try to console value inside constructor it gives undefined but in onInit method it gives

```
coverages = [
        { name: 'Austin', gender: 'Male', company: 'Swimlane' },
        { name: 'Dany', gender: 'Male', company: 'KFC' },
        { name: 'Molly', gender: 'Female', company: 'Burger King' },
      ];
```

Now on my html I see

```
<ng-component>
       <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-cp-loop-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->
```

how to see this list rendered in my directive

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wn8wbw?file=app%2Fapp.component.html But it looks like very strange directive

Comment: plz share any example in which this requirement fulfill. I have to simply use ngFor in my template and it will be use throughout the pages so I want to do it trough directive in next step I have create a grid structure.

Comment: how to make directive with template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586743/adding-a-link-template-column-to-a-custom-table-component/42588759#42588759

Comment: in that example I am unable to understand where @Directive({
    selector: '[tableTemplate]'
}) has been used